# (Java)Why some people still use the awt library and not the swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I often see YouTube tutorials about making Java GUIs where the swing library is not used, instead of Swing they use AWT.
What are the advantages? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: The java.awt library is mostly used by tutors to make thier student familiar with the java GUI components.

Comment: Not all Java implementations include Swing.

Comment: Swing is now also outdated. Probably you should look about Java FX. Please look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) for more info.

Comment: In practise you rarely use awt... But recently i was trying to find a way to create a systray icon/menu in javafx  and only awt had an api to access this functionality in windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here are a few other advantages to Swing over AWT which I found on http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=106026:

> - Swing provides both additional components and added functionality to    AWT-replacement components
> - Swing components can change their appearance based on the current    "look and feel" library that's being used. You can use the same look
>     and feel as the platform you're on, or use a different look and feel
> - Swing components follow the Model-View-Controller paradigm (MVC), and    thus can provide a much more flexible UI.
> - Swing provides "extras" for components, such as:
>
>   - Icons on many components
>   - Decorative borders for components
>   - Tooltips for components
> - Swing components are lightweight (less resource intensive than
> - Swing provides built-in double buffering
> - Swing provides paint debugging support for when you build your own
>
> components
>
> Swing also has a few disadvantages:
>
> - It requires Java 2 or a separate JAR file
> - If you're not very careful when programming, it can be slower than    AWT (all components are drawn)
> - Swing components that look like native components might not act    exactly like native components

Moreover! habit is everything..They will do in which they have practice.But I prefer Swing but we eventually need AWT for event handling purpose or Layout

Comment: First disadvantage can be removed. Today we have Java 9.